# PCL_library_Exception_thrown-Unhandled exception_pcl::IOException at memory location

Tags: c++, visual-studio, point-cloud-library

I tried the tutorial "Construct a concave or convex hull polygon for a plane model"(http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/hull_2d.php#hull-2d) from the official PCL site:

```
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>), 
                                      cloud_filtered (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>), 
                                      cloud_projected (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
  pcl::PCDReader reader;

  reader.read ("table_scene_mug_stereo_textured.pcd", *cloud);
  // Build a filter to remove spurious NaNs
  pcl::PassThrough<pcl::PointXYZ> pass;
  pass.setInputCloud (cloud);
  pass.setFilterFieldName ("z");
  pass.setFilterLimits (0, 1.1);
  pass.filter (*cloud_filtered);
  std::cerr << "PointCloud after filtering has: "
            << cloud_filtered->points.size () << " data points." << std::endl;

  pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr coefficients (new pcl::ModelCoefficients);
  pcl::PointIndices::Ptr inliers (new pcl::PointIndices);
  // Create the segmentation object
  pcl::SACSegmentation<pcl::PointXYZ> seg;
  // Optional
  seg.setOptimizeCoefficients (true);
  // Mandatory
  seg.setModelType (pcl::SACMODEL_PLANE);
  seg.setMethodType (pcl::SAC_RANSAC);
  seg.setDistanceThreshold (0.01);

  seg.setInputCloud (cloud_filtered);
  seg.segment (*inliers, *coefficients);
  std::cerr << "PointCloud after segmentation has: "
            << inliers->indices.size () << " inliers." << std::endl;

  // Project the model inliers
  pcl::ProjectInliers<pcl::PointXYZ> proj;
  proj.setModelType (pcl::SACMODEL_PLANE);
  proj.setIndices (inliers);
  proj.setInputCloud (cloud_filtered);
  proj.setModelCoefficients (coefficients);
  proj.filter (*cloud_projected);
  std::cerr << "PointCloud after projection has: "
            << cloud_projected->points.size () << " data points." << std::endl;

  // Create a Concave Hull representation of the projected inliers
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud_hull (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
  pcl::ConcaveHull<pcl::PointXYZ> chull;
  chull.setInputCloud (cloud_projected);
  chull.setAlpha (0.1);
  chull.reconstruct (*cloud_hull);

  std::cerr << "Concave hull has: " << cloud_hull->points.size ()
            << " data points." << std::endl;

  pcl::PCDWriter writer;
  writer.write ("table_scene_mug_stereo_textured_hull.pcd", *cloud_hull, false);

  return (0);
}
```

and everything worked fine. When I ran the program for my own .pcd file, I have the following error:

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FFCE7561F28 in concave_hull_2d.exe:
>   Microsoft C++ exception: pcl::IOException at memory location
>   0x0000006C00D4F468.
>
> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFCE7561F28 in concave_hull_2d.exe:
>   Microsoft C++ exception: pcl::IOException at memory location
>   0x0000006C00D4F468.

I use PCL 1.8.0 and MCVS2015. I don't know how can i deal with that problem. Any comment would be valuable!

Comment: Did you try to run the program under a debugger and see where it gets stuck?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The problem is here:

Comment: @ Dexter 'pcl::PCDWriter::writeASCII (const std::string &file_name, const '
I took this function from the code and replaced it with a similar and the program works fine. I don't know why this occured with my own .pcd file.